# Xcode, clang, c++ stdlib: Swift Package using a system library, build fails with 'stdexcept' file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, wrapper, swift-package-manager, xcode-command-line-tools

I am writing an executable Swift package where I need to use a system library (written in C++).

AFAIK I have the package.swift, module.modulemap and umbrella header file written correctly.

When I add an `import` for the library in my `main.swift` file I get an error `'stdexcept' file not found`.  The error comes from an `#include <stdexcept>` in one of the system library's public header files.

Currently running:

- Xcode v13.2.1
- macOS v12.2.1 (Monterey)

I think the problem is related to Xcode's Command Line Tools but how do I fix it?

Package.swift

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "GeodesicApp",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v11)],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
      .systemLibrary(name: "geographiclib",
                     pkgConfig: "geographiclib",
                     providers: [
                      .brew(["geographiclib"])
                     ]
                    ),
        .executableTarget(
            name: "GeodesicApp",
            dependencies: ["geographiclib"])
    ]
)
```

module.modulemap

```swift
module geographiclib {
  umbrella header "geographiclib.h"
  export *
  link "geographiclib"
}
```

Umbrella header (geographiclib.h)

```c
#include <GeographicLib/Config.h>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>
```

main.swift

```swift
import geographiclib     // error: 'stdexcept' file not found

...  //
```

Error.
[image: XCode Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
I was only able to get a working solution by creating a C wrapper package around the system library; that C wrapper package, in turn, is then wrapped with another Swift wrapper to expose 'Swifty-style' code  - I was not able to get a single package that included all the required parts.

My working solution is as follows...

### Package: CGeographicLib

Folder structure for the the system library's C wrapper is:

```
.
├── Package.swift
├── README.md
└── Sources
    ├── CGeographicLib
    │   ├── CGeodesic.cpp
    │   └── include
    │       └── CGeodesic.h
    └── geographiclib
        ├── geographiclib.h
        └── module.modulemap
```

Updated `Package.swift`:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CGeographicLib",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v11)],
    products: [
      .library(name: "CGeographicLib", targets: ["CGeographicLib"])
    ],
    targets: [
      .systemLibrary(name: "geographiclib",
                     pkgConfig: "geographiclib",
                     providers: [
                      .brew(["geographiclib"])
                     ]),
      .target(name: "CGeographicLib", dependencies: ["geographiclib"])
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: .cxx20
)
```

I added `platforms: [.macOS(.v11)]` as the latest version of the `GeographicLib` system library only supports macOS v11 or later.

The system library that I am using has some C++11 extensions, I added the language standard `.cxx20`, but this could equally be `.cxx11` too and it should still work for the system library I am using.

Updated `module.modulemap`:

```swift
module geographiclib [system] {
  umbrella header "geographiclib.h"
  link "geographiclib"
  export *
}
```

Umbrella header, `geographiclib.h` is unchanged.

For the new C wrapper elements:
`CGeodesic.h`:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"  {
#endif

double geoLibInverse(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`CGeodesic.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "include/CGeodesic.h"
#include "../../geographiclib/geographiclib.h"

double geoLibInverse(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
  
  using namespace std;
  using namespace GeographicLib;
  
  Geodesic geod(Constants::WGS84_a(), Constants::WGS84_f());
  double s12;
  geod.Inverse(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, s12);
    
  return s12;
}
```

---

### Package: SwiftyGeographicLib

Folder structure for the Swift package that uses the C wrapper package is:

```
.
├── Package.swift
├── README.md
├── Sources
│   └── SwiftyGeographicLib
│       └── Geodesic.swift
└── Tests
    └── SwiftyGeographicLibTests
        └── SwiftyGeographicLibTests.swift
```

`Package.swift`:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftyGeographicLib",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v11)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SwiftyGeographicLib",
            targets: ["SwiftyGeographicLib"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
      .package(name: "CGeographicLib",
               url: "/Users/kieran/codeProjects/z.TestProjects/SPM/CGeographicLib",
               branch: "master")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SwiftyGeographicLib",
            dependencies: ["CGeographicLib"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SwiftyGeographicLibTests",
            dependencies: ["SwiftyGeographicLib"]),
    ]
)
```

The package dependency in this example is pointing to a local package - I could equally have uploaded and created a version tag on GitHub.

`Geodesic.swift`:

```swift
import Foundation
import CGeographicLib

public func geodesicInverse(lat1: Double, lon1: Double, lat2: Double, lon2: Double) -> Double {
  
  return geoLibInverse(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
}
```